# What is the html pattern to allow numbers characters and dots in input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have input field type is text.

What is the pattern to allow Numbers, characters and Dot(special character) to input field?

Comment: What patterns have you tried so far?

Comment: pattern="[A-Za-z]" for texts, I want to allow ex : 5.5 Ft

Comment: `pattern="[\w\.]"` ?

Comment: ah yes, `\w` is alphanumeric and underscore, I think.

Comment: pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\.]" tried with this, and entered 5.5 FT, but it is not moving to another field.

Comment: @kumar "moving to another field" this won't be done automatically, it must be done using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="text"]:valid{
color:green;
}

input[type="text"]:invalid{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9\.]*$" value="test1234.">
```

Comment: No need to escape `.` inside character class.